# Estructura adecuada

Tags: estructuras-de-datos, ms-access, mdb

Necesito saber cuál sería la estructura dinámica más adecuada para cargar los registros de un *ID* y un *Timestamp* de 3000 ocurrencias aproximadamente. Corresponde a los datos de un terminal de registro de entrada o salida de personal con huellas digitales. Los valores son *Id* y *Timestamp* (fecha y hora).

Ejemplo:

```
ID  TIMESTAMP
37  01-01-17 12:08:07 AM
17  01-01-17 12:10:15 AM
14  01-01-17 12:44:14 AM
```

Los registros, son secuenciales en el tiempo. Lo que necesito es extraer cuántas horas ha trabajado cada *Id* por día del mes que corresponda indistintamente de la cantidad de registros que cada uno posea en el día. El reloj almacena en una base de datos de *Access*, formato *MDB*. Necesito leerlo y registrarlo en *Golang*.

Answer (score 0):

Usarias la estructura de datos MAP, el que te permite enlazar una llave con su respectivo contenido

```
Map<ClaseParalaLLave, ClaseParaContenido>
```

ejemplo

```
 Map<Integer,String> map=new HashMap<Integer,String>();  
  map.put(37,"01-01-17 12:08:07 AM");  
  map.put(17,"01-01-17 12:10:15 AM");  
  map.put(14,"01-01-17 12:44:14 AM");  
  for(Map.Entry m:map.entrySet()){  
   System.out.println(m.getKey()+" "+m.getValue());  
  }
```